# Labels removed from this.Controls keep reappearing

Tags: c#, sharepoint-2010, controls

I am a novice `C#` programmer, trying to create a simple `RSS/Atom` aggregator webpart for a `SharePoint` site (I can't use the ootb part as I don't have an Enterprise licence).

I have 3 buttons:

1. New Feed, which takes a `URI` from the user and attempts to construct a label displaying the feed and add it to `this.Controls;`
2. Clear Feeds, which clears all the displayed feeds (removing them from `this.Controls`)
3. Default Feeds, which takes an `ArrayList` of default `URIs` and converts them each into labels (also adding them to `this.Controls`).

Clearing the feeds works fine, as does reverting to the defaults. However, after clearing all the feeds and trying to add a new feed, the defaults are added as well (and only one new feed can be added at a time, the new one overwriting the old). I suspect this is because I don't fully understand the add/remove controls function. Code follows below:

```
    ArrayList viewedFeeds = new ArrayList(); 
    ArrayList defaultFeeds = new ArrayList(); //Contains several default feeds, e.g. BBC news (http://feeds.bbci.co.uk/news/rss.xml)

    private void newFeed_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        renderFeed(userText.Text);
    }

    private void clearFeeds_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        clearAllFeeds();
    }

    private void defaultFeeds_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        clearAllFeeds();
        initialiseFeedViewer();
    }

    private void clearAllFeeds()
    {
        foreach (Label feed in viewedFeeds)
        {
            this.Controls.Remove(feed);
        }
        viewedFeeds.Clear();
    }

    private void initialiseFeedViewer()
    {
        foreach (string uri in defaultFeeds)
            renderFeed(uri);
    }

    private void renderFeed(String uri)  
    {
        try  
        {  
            Label feed = new Label();

            // Create a Syndicated feed reader, parse the XML and add the relevant text to the label "feed"
            feed.BorderStyle = System.Web.UI.WebControls.BorderStyle.Double;
            viewedFeeds.Add(feed);
            this.Controls.Add(feed);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {   
            //Print an error message (e.g. If the URI does not link to a suitable feed
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out I *was* calling `initialiseFeedViewer()` more than once - it was in the `createChildControls()` method. I assumed this was only called once, similar to a constructor, but it seems to be called every time the page is loaded.

This has the annoying side effect of clearing all of my variables, so the `List<Label>`s I'm using to keep track of displayed feeds are rendered useless.

I'll attempt to get around this by storing them in a Sharepoint List instead.

Answer (score 0):

For you're problem of being unable to add more than one control at a time. Try setting the "Name" property of the label before you try adding it to the arraylist and the "panel" you are using to hold you're label controls.

```
private void renderFeed(String uri)  
{
    try  
    {  
        Label feed = new Label();
        feed.Name = uri;
        //Create a Syndicated feed reader, parse the XML and add the relevant text to the label "feed"
        feed.BorderStyle = System.Web.UI.WebControls.BorderStyle.Double;
        viewedFeeds.Add(uri);
        this.Controls.Add(feed);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {   
        //Print an error message (e.g. If the URI does not link to a suitable feed
    }
}
```

As for it rendering your defaults when you add a new one. I would just make sure you're not calling the initialiseFeedViewer() on accident.

Just as a sidenote, arraylist is considered to be depreciated. Consider using List instead.

```
List<string> viewedFeeds = new List<string>();
List<string> defaultFeeds = new List<string>();
```

Comment: `Label` doesn't seem to have a `Name` property. Does it mater that this is a `WebControl.Label`?
Thanks for the heads up about the `ArrayList` though, I was stuck in `Java` mode

Comment: Also, checking the call hierarchy in Visual Studio, I can see `initialiseFeedViewer()` only has two calls to it: one at the start of the program and one when the `Default Feeds` button is clicked.

Comment: Hmm, instead of label.Name try label.ID